# What does Pacific Time translate to in Joda time

Tags: java, timezone, jodatime

I'm using joda time and I need to know which joda timezone to use if I want Pacific Time. I saw several jodatime timezones:

- Pacific/Honolulu
- America/Los_Angeles
- America/Vancouver
- PST8PDT

Which one is the most appropriate joda timezone when people say "Pacific Time" in real world?

Thanks

Comment: Los Angeles is fine.

Comment: The most unambiguous is the last one (PST8PDT). "Pacific Time" is usually UTC-0800 (with DST adjustment) but used unqualified it is probably ambiguous in some parts of the world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, recognize that "Pacific Time" is a legal name in some places, and a convention in others.

Next, realize that the identifiers you mention are not just for Joda Time, but are the standard set of IANA TZDB identifiers.  You can find [a list here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), or read more about them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).

Going through your list:

- `Pacific/Honolulu` does not work, "Pacific" here refers to the Pacific Ocean, not the Pacific time zone.  Hawaii is UTC-10, which is far from the UTC-8 used by PST, or the UTC-7 used by PDT.
- `America/Los_Angeles` this is the best identifier for Pacific Time - *in the United States*.
- `America/Vancouver` this is the best identifier for Pacific Time - *in Canada*.
- `America/Tijuana` is not in your list, but would be the best identifier for Pacific Time - *in Mexico*.
- `PST8PDT` - technically this will work, but only because it's one of the few POSIX tz identifiers that was copied into the tzdb for backwards compatibility purposes (with systems that have long since died off).  In general, you should not use POSIX identifiers, for the reasons described in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Also note that there are indeed difference between the last four entries - mostly to do with historical data.  You can dig into the TZDB's [northamerica](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/northamerica) file if you want to know the precise differences.  They're not worth mentioning here.

Comment: OK, so from your post, I'm deducing that my best bet is either America/Los_Angeles or America/Vancouver. I'm guessing that there wont be any difference between the 2? will there be any case where those 2 show different time? Thanks

Comment: As I said, you can diff the entries in the file to see the differences.  You can also look at sites like timeanddate.com to compare them.  Essentially, Vancouver and Los Angeles have been the same since 1976, but have some variations before then (especially 1974 and 1975 in Los Angeles).